# Could not load type module C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, httpmodule

I am very new to VS for web applications and modules,

I am trying to run/debug a http module so I followed this helpful tutorial:

https://dotnetcodr.com/2015/07/10/how-to-register-a-custom-http-module-in-your-net-web-application/

and I got to debug his test module inside my sample WebApplication.

Now I linked my module inside that sample WebApplication, I edited the **Web.config** replacing this:

```
  <add name="DescriptiveNameOfModule" type="HttpModuleTestApplication.Modules.TestModule"/>
```

with my module

```
  <add name="DescriptiveNameOfModule" type="MyHttpModule11.MyHttpModule"/>
```

but when I run it I am getting a page containing the following error:

```
    [HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load type 'MyHttpModule11.MyHttpModule'.]
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase) +9972697
   System.Web.Configuration.ConfigUtil.GetType(String typeName, String propertyName, ConfigurationElement configElement, XmlNode node, Boolean checkAptcaBit, Boolean ignoreCase) +38

[ConfigurationErrorsException: Could not load type 'MyHttpModule11.MyHttpModule'.]
   System.Web.Configuration.ConfigUtil.GetType(String typeName, String propertyName, ConfigurationElement configElement, XmlNode node, Boolean checkAptcaBit, Boolean ignoreCase) +353
   System.Web.Configuration.ConfigUtil.GetType(String typeName, String propertyName, ConfigurationElement configElement, Boolean checkAptcaBit) +21
   System.Web.Configuration.Common.ModulesEntry.SecureGetType(String typeName, String propertyName, ConfigurationElement configElement) +39
   System.Web.Configuration.Common.ModulesEntry..ctor(String name, String typeName, String propertyName, ConfigurationElement configElement) +42
   System.Web.HttpApplication.BuildIntegratedModuleCollection(List`1 moduleList) +160
   System.Web.HttpApplication.GetModuleCollection(IntPtr appContext) +1068
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +82
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +173
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +336
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +296

[HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load type 'MyHttpModule11.MyHttpModule'.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +10085804
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +95
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +254
```

What could be the reason?
Might it be caused by an IIS different version?

Comment: Is the name of your module so sensitive that you have replaced it with '[package].[classname]' above? If it is 'MyHttpModule11.IHttpModule' then perhaps the problem is related to trying to load an interface rather than a concrete class?

Comment: thanks @Cal279, the name is not so sensitive, I will edit my post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may need to include the name of the assembly in which this type resides. eg.

```
<modules>
    <add name="DescriptiveNameOfModule" type="MyHttpModule11.MyHttpModule, AssemblyNameWithoutExtension"/>
</modules>
```

Comment: what is the assembly in my case? the class name, the module name?

Comment: It would most likely be the same as the name of the dll (without the ".dll" at the end).